# CSS3 high consume resource

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing a hybrid app using ionic. I mainly customize the ionic main css via scss, and also add some of my custom css. Currently the app layout is done without much JS logic and it runs on crosswalk. The layout does shows up nicely, however on low end smartphone, it doesn't seems to be running smoothly.

So, I am here to ask, what CSS element is consider high resource consuming? Is the shadow consume resource? What is the best practice to develop high performance CSS layout?

Comment: If I had to guess, animation. Not sure how to test though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Ionic forum moderator (also a blogger) so let me give you few tips and tricks.

No matter what framework you use, low-level Android smartphones will always be a problem. Though almost everything can be fixed.

Most common CSS3 features causing performance problems are:

- shadows (worst of them all - box and text shadows)
- opacity
- gradients (least problematic of these three)

You should always use CSS3 hardware accelerated features, move us much of processing to GPU, thus moving CPU to other tasks.

I wrote an article on this topic, find it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/speed-up-your-ionic-application-using-these-techniques/)**.

There's one more thing. Probably two biggest problems on low-level smartphones are view animations (transitions) and list performance.

If you have a huge list use collection repeat (Ionic feature), unfortunately, you can use native JavaScript scrolling with it. But if you have a smaller list, you can use classic ng-repeat and turn on native scrolling. It will improve a look and feel.

Another thing, view transitions can be improved (to almost perfect state) using Cordova Native Transitions plugin. Here's a working example including video differences, click **[here](http://:)**.

Or take a look here:

#### Classic CSS animations (bad performance):

https://www.youtube.com/embed/niHxogcq2F8

#### Native Transition animations:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/mJifdqoIJ_s

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help and very good blog on applying native transition with ionic framework. It just feel awesome to get your reply here. Now I am trying to get native transition to work with ionic side-menu. But it seems a bit "weird" with the animation. I have posted my question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411074/ionic-sidemenu-with-native-page-transitions).  It would be nice if you could write an article on getting native transition for ionic side-menu. I'm sure it will be very beneficial to everyone as side-menu is one of the most common use element.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start removing all css files and test *low end devices* again, to see if the bad performances are css related or not.

Anyway, start writing [efficient css selector](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) avoiding [bad css properties](http://nerds.airbnb.com/box-shadows-are-expensive-to-paint/), and learn [how to profile your web application](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) using [remote debugging tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) (there are similar tools in safari/ios). Also keep you updated reading [dedicated blog posts](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/css-paint-times/) from many authors you can find online.